# Two Kinetic.Tween aren't executed at the EXACT same time || Get updated x-value during Tween

Tags: html, animation, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to keep a stage static and non-draggable on a draggable stage.

So far, it works when the users drags the stage with the mouse by catching the `dragmove` -event(no visual problems there), but as I am intended to finish the complete swiping with some smooth easings I attached two `Kinetic.Tween` to it (in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4xuG/) reachable by pressing "Start tweens").

They are doing their job pretty well, but as you can probably see in my example, there is a little delay in the execution of both tweens, which causes the green rectangle to shiver during the execution.

Is there a way to get rid of this little delay in the execution or how else could I get the updated x-value of the stage to recalculate the green rectangles x like I'm doing it in the `dragmove` event?

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve my problem simply by adding an eventlistener to the `xChange` property, wich allows me to use the `var dx = stage.getX(); rect.setX(-dx)` calculation I'm using during `dragmove` with the updated x-value of the stage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your real scenario but it would be better if you left static objects in different layers and, instead of tween the whole stage, tween only the specific layers, in this case, the layer that contains the background.

[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/Jwcrx/)

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 400
    // <-- remove drag function
});

var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: stage.getWidth(),
    height: stage.getHeight(),
    fill: '#FF0000'
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) { // <-- added drag function here
        return {
            x: pos.x,
            y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
        }
    }
});
var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer(); // create new layer

layer.add(background);
stage.add(layer);

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});

layer2.add(rect); // <-- added rect on layer2
stage.add(layer2); // <-- added layer2 to stage

layer.drawScene();
layer2.drawScene(); // <-- draw layer2

stage.on('dragmove', function () {
    var dx = stage.getX();
    rect.setX(-dx);
});

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    new Kinetic.Tween({
        node: layer, // <-- changed stage to layer 
        x: -300,
        duration: 0.5,
        easing: Kinetic.Easings.EaseInOut
    }).play();

    // rect tween removed
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my real scenario I have 5+ pages, which are all represented by layers. So I would guess that tweening the whole stage and only one layer (the one I'm having issues with)  requires less cpu-power than tweening every single page-layer.